# How to count complete sets of items in php?

Tags: php

I am a newbie, so hopefully I word this properly.  I have searched and searched both SO and the web to try to find this answer, even mathematically, to understand how to code it, but to no avail.

On a web game, I want to be able to count the number of complete sets a user has (the set has four items).

For example, the user can attain turkey, pumpkin pie, stuffing, and mashed potatoes.  Those are displayed in a table by quantity, like so:

Mashed Potatoes:   2
Turkey:            4
Pumpkin Pie:       4
Stuffing:          3

So in this case, the user has 2 total sets of what I'll call a "Thanksgiving Dinner."  The Thanksgiving Dinner must include one of each item to be a complete set.

How can I use PHP to count and display the number of complete sets the user has?

This feels like it should be so simple (mathematically, at least), but I am really struggling.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, simple, as shown in this [**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/e49y-h3mx)

```
<?php
    $min = 100000; // just initialize min with large value.
    // these values can be hard coded, from JSON, html form, or database
    // it is just written for illustration
    $arr = array(
        'Mashed Potatoes' => 2,
        'Turkey' => 4,
        'Pumpkin Pie'=> 4,
        'Stuffing'=> 3
    );

    // we loop through each element of the above array and,
    // compare its value to the min.
    foreach($arr as $value){
        if( $value < $min){
            // If the value is less that min. then we store value into min
            $min = $value;
        }
    }
    echo 'You can have ' . $min . ' Thanksgiving dinners';
?>
```

***EDIT:***
As suggested in a comment from PaparazzoKi, Thanks, you can replace all of this:

```
foreach($arr as $value){
        if( $value < $min){
            // If the value is less that min. then we store value into min
            $min = $value;
        }
    }
    echo 'You can have ' . $min . ' Thanksgiving dinners';
```

With this line:

```
echo 'You can have ' . min($arr) . ' Thanksgiving dinners';
```

Making use of the `.min()` function

Comment: Surely what your doing there is the same as `You can have '.min($arr).' Thanksgiving dinners`? Therefore, doing away with the `foreach` loop altogether.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid to be honest I haven't think of  this function before, thanks a lot for reminding

Answer (score -1):

The total number of complete set will the the key with the lowest value in the array.

You may use the min() function of PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php